# Append a list in a list from a for loop

Tags: list, for-loop, append, python-3.7

Hello Stackoverflowers,

My question:
A for loop (j), that cycles three times, I add every time one values with append(). This for loop is placed in another for loop (i). In this for loop, that also cycles three times, I use append() to add the list from for loop (j) in a second list. When I print the second list, I see three times the results from the first list added in the third cycle.

```
list_batteries = [ 50,  75, 100]
list_chargers  = [100, 250, 500]

list_results   = []
list_temp = []

for i in range(len(list_batteries)):
    list_temp.clear()
    for j in range(len(list_chargers)):
        list_temp.append(list_chargers[j] / list_batteries[i])
    list_results.append(list_temp)

print(list_results)
```

The `print(list_results)` gives me:

```
[[1.0, 2.5, 5.0], [1.0, 2.5, 5.0], [1.0, 2.5, 5.0]]
```

But I want:

```
[[2.0, 5.0, 10.0], [1.3333333333333333, 3.3333333333333335, 6.666666666666667], [1.0, 2.5, 5.0]]
```

So, I can get a value with `list_results[...][...]`.

I really appreciate it if someone can explain to me why I don't get the expected result and how I should write the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line, after the first loop over `i`:

`list_temp.clear()`

This line clears not only `list_temp` but also `list_batteries`. This is why you always start a new iteration with both clear lists.

I admit I don't know why, but reassigning `list_temp` to `[]`, instead of calling the `clear` method works perfectly:

```
list_batteries = [50, 75, 100]
list_chargers = [100, 250, 500]

list_results = []
list_temp = []

for i in range(len(list_batteries)):
    list_temp = [] #MODIFY HERE
    for j in range(len(list_chargers)):
        list_temp.append(list_chargers[j] / list_batteries[i])
    list_results.append(list_temp)

print(list_results)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found an another option thanks to Sreekanth BM. He said to use `list_results.append(list(list_temp))`. With this I can still use `list_temp.clear()` without a problem.

Comment: Sure. Whatever fits you.

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying to append list to list, use:
**list_results.append(list(list_temp))** rather than list_results.append(list_temp)

And nullify list_temp *=0

```
list_batteries = [ 50,  75, 100]
list_chargers  = [100, 250, 500]

list_results   = []
list_temp = []

for i in range(len(list_batteries)):
    list_temp *=0
    for j in range(len(list_chargers)):
        list_temp.append(list_chargers[j] / list_batteries[i])
    list_results.append(list(list_temp))

print(list_results)
```